# Create hidden configuration file for C++ Linux applications

Tags: c++, linux, configuration-files

I'm creating a C++ linux application that needs some initial parameters of configuration to work correctly, these externals configurations is needed to avoid multiple compilations for parameters changes, and this configurations needs to be unknow by the end users. I was thinking an way do make an hidden configuration file that is consumed at the first execution, and always is researched at execution to verify possibles changes. Some suggestion to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? What do you mean by "consumed" (deleted?)? Also what is "researched at execution"?

Comment: *"and this configurations needs to be unknow by the end users"* What do you mean by that? The user is not supposed to see it with his normal UI? -> Use a .bla file. The user is not supposed to be able to see it? This won't be possible if you are going to use it on his system.

Comment: @Smeeheey I said "consumed" with the purpose of delete the file after de application configuration and "researched at execution" means that the application always looking for a new configuration at the start of they execution.

Comment: @BaummitAugen "and this configurations needs to be unknow by the end users" means that this configuration is hidden to the user, is not interesting for the user change this configurations and "researched at execution" means that the application always looking for a new configuration at the start of they execution.

Comment: @JulianOliveira In that case, name it ".somename" (the important part being a leading '.' followed by some letter(s)). This indicates that this file is to be hidden by default to all UI programs.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you can hide the configuration file so that people do not know its existence: most Linux users would want to know which files you are installing in which location, and there are many ways to help them in discovering that, even if you try to do it without telling them (the simplest way that comes to my mind, they may do a file system snapshot and compare it before and after running the install program)

If your goal is to prevent people from changing the configuration without your permission (i.e., without paying for a license upgrade), you may do it by requiring the configuration to be signed from your company, storing the verification key inside the executable.

If you want to prevent the configuration from being read you don't have that much luck: there is not much that can stop a motivated attacker from reading the content of that file, since your application must be able to do it as well.